# .htaccess Internal Redirect issue

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Something with my .htaccess file is creating a rule loop of some sort when a certain condition exists. Here is the code in question:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /%1.php?o=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1.php [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Normally what this does is:

```
test.example.com -> example.com/test.php
test.example.com/test2 -> example.com/test.php?o=test2
```

Thats fine, except when the "test" subdomain part points to a nonexistent file, I get an internal redirect error, specifically this:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: [retracted]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will cause looping because `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will still be true for `/test.php` when `/test.php` doesn't exist.

You can use this code to prevent looping:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# don't redirect after one internal redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .+
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /%1.php?o=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked (I'm really not good with understanding htaccess so sorry if this was a pretty obvious answer)